# ember-simple-auth and torii firebase TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: firebase, ember.js, ember-simple-auth, emberfire

I started out getting torri and emberfire to work for a login page but when I try to use that with ember simple auth I get the error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at Class.persist (local-storage.js:45)
    at Class.persist (adaptive.js:163)
    at Class._callStoreAsync (internal-session.js:132)
    at Class._updateStore (internal-session.js:207)
    at Class._setup (internal-session.js:156)
    at internal-session.js:61
    at tryCatch (ember.debug.js:50180)
    at invokeCallback (ember.debug.js:50195)
    at publish (ember.debug.js:50163)
```

Not sure if its a bug or I'm missing something that needs setting up. Made a quick repo which shows my problem https://github.com/tobias-g/ember-simple-auth-firebase where the diff https://github.com/tobias-g/ember-simple-auth-firebase/commit/02882f4db3a0320d4ac314d2e92192ac522470f8 shows what I added to try and get ember simple auth to work.

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember             : 2.13.3
DEBUG: Ember Data        : 2.13.1
DEBUG: Firebase          : 3.9.0
DEBUG: EmberFire         : 0.0.0
DEBUG: jQuery            : 3.2.1
DEBUG: Ember Simple Auth : 1.3.0
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

Comment: You know, Firebase has it's own authentication system in place that already uses Torii. I don't know what you're use case is, but I found that ember-simple-auth and Firebase was redundant. https://github.com/firebase/emberfire/blob/master/docs/guide/authentication.md

Comment: Yea I got the firebase authentication working fine in the first commit but would like to use the ember-simple-auth DataAdapterMixin for my models and AuthenticatedRouteMixin for routes. If I can't fix it I'll guess I have to deal with that myself without the mixins and probably have to write a bit more boilerplate code.

Answer (score 3):

The `data.authenticated` payload sent back by Emberfire is too complex and has circular references. Ember Simple Auth stores this payload to local storage to prevent log-in prompts when refreshing or opening the app on other tabs.

What *seems* to work for me now (I haven't tested much) is extending the session store. YMMV.

```
// app/session-stores/application.js

import AdaptiveStore from 'ember-simple-auth/session-stores/adaptive';

export default AdaptiveStore.extend({

  persist(data) {
    const a = data.authenticated;

    const subset = {
      authenticator: a.authenticator,
      email: a.email,
      provider: a.provider,
      refreshToken: a.refreshToken,
      uid: a.uid
    }

    return this._super({ authenticated: subset });
  }

});
```